# How to create a random list of strings using recursion?

Tags: c#, string

I want to generate a random list of strings containing only alphanumeric characters. The length of the string can be of any size. Is there any way to do this using recursion?

Comment: I kind of have a method to do it in the normal way. I want to know whether there is a way to do it recursively.

Comment: Indeed, the recursive bit sounds odd.  As with all recursive problems, the most important question is, when do you stop?  What parameter will tell the function to stop calling itself?  If it is just a number, a simple loop is more efficient and reads better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you explicitly asked for recursion, here is a recursive solution. It’s very slow, though.

```
static string allowedCharacters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
static Random rnd = new Random();
static string randomString(int length)
{
    if (length == 0)
        return "";
    return allowedCharacters[rnd.Next(0, allowedCharacters.Length)]
           + randomString(length - 1);   // This is the recursive call.
}
```

Now you can use this to generate a string of a random length:

```
// Outputs a random string of a length between 5 and 49 characters
Console.WriteLine(randomString(rnd.Next(5, 50)));
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no need for recursion in this. Simply write down the characters you want in your string, for example:

```
string allowedCharacters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
```

Then you can simply grab characters from this by random:

```
Random rnd = new Random();
string randomString(int length)
{
    int num = allowedCharacters.Length;
    return new string(Enumerable.Range(0, length)
           .Select(i => allowedCharacters[rnd.Next(0, num)])
           .ToArray());
}
```

Finally, you can use this to generate a string of a random length:

```
// Outputs a random string of a length between 5 and 49 characters
Console.WriteLine(randomString(rnd.Next(5, 50)));
```

Comment: I am still a little new to the use of C#. No offense, but isn't there a simpler way to do this? I mean the whole 
"return new string(Enumerable.Range(0, length)
           .Select(i => allowedCharacters[rnd.Next(0, num)])
           .ToArray());
"
has got me a little confusing.

Comment: That depends on how you define “simple”. Of course I can write it without `Enumerable.Range` and without `Select`, but it would be more verbose. (It would also be faster, but that’s not usually part of the definition of “simple”.)